# How to restore original client IP from Cloudflare with NGINX ingress controller

Tags: docker, nginx, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, cloudflare

I'm using Cloudflare as CDN and it's hiding the real IP address for the clients
I'm using an NGINX ingress controller as a loadbalancer running in Google Kubernetes engine 
So I'm trying to restore the original IP address and trying to follow this link https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170706-How-do-I-restore-original-visitor-IP-with-Nginx-
How can I implement this in the configmap for my Nginx ingress since I need multiple value for the same key "set-real-ip-from" ?

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingressname
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "0"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: "cookie"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name: "route"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-expires: "172800"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-max-age: "172800"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - example.com
    secretName: sslcertificate
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: service
          servicePort: 80
        path: /
```

Answer (score 13):

I also had this problem and it took me forever to fix but apparently all I needed was this configuration:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  # Cloudflare IP ranges which you can find on https://www.cloudflare.com/ips/
  proxy-real-ip-cidr: "173.245.48.0/20,103.21.244.0/22,103.22.200.0/22,103.31.4.0/22,141.101.64.0/18,108.162.192.0/18,190.93.240.0/20,188.114.96.0/20,197.234.240.0/22,198.41.128.0/17,162.158.0.0/15,104.16.0.0/13,104.24.0.0/14,172.64.0.0/13,131.0.72.0/22,2400:cb00::/32,2606:4700::/32,2803:f800::/32,2405:b500::/32,2405:8100::/32,2a06:98c0::/29,2c0f:f248::/32"
  # This is the important part
  use-forwarded-headers: "true"
  # Still works without this line because it defaults to X-Forwarded-For, but I use it anyways
  forwarded-for-header: "CF-Connecting-IP"
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: nginx-configuration
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
```

IMO this is all really unclear from the documentation. I had to search through tons of issues and the actual template file itself to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

In order to retrieve data from `X-Forwarded-For` header and get a real IP address for the clients you have to enable proxy protocol in particular Nginx Ingress controller [ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/#configmaps) and then add IP/networks for a visitors.

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  proxy-real-ip-cidr: 103.21.244.0/22,103.22.200.0/22,103.31.4.0/22
  use-proxy-protocol: "true"
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  labels:
    app: nginx-ingress
  name: nginx-ingress-controller
  namespace: default
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: I tried your solution but i got this error "[error] 278#278: *183435 broken header: "�����X�~���J�$bBN/qBS�X�E/��`B�*��� ���Ge�K�b1���,(��@�`�{�����h��+�/����/�,�(�5�
����" while reading PROXY protocol, client: 162.158.75.71, server: 0.0.0.0:443"

Comment: Can you share `Ingress` object configuration?

Comment: I edited the description for the question above. Also I'm using the following image for the nginx ingress controller "quay.io/kubernetes-ingress-controller/nginx-ingress-controller:0.24.1"

Comment: Have you tried to disable proxy protocol: `use-proxy-protocol: "false"`? What was the behavior?

Comment: yes i tried that .. normal behavior ... but i still get the Cloudflare IP

Comment: Might be relevant for your scenario, just check this Github [thread](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/3996).

Comment: this latest version "0.24.1" of "nginx-ingress-controller" I upgraded to, by default doesn't show the real IP address. So as a temporary solution for now, I downgraded to another recent version that did the job. Thanks for your help, I really appreciate it.