# Restore Client IP behind Ingress

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, digital-ocean, cloudflare, nginx-ingress

I have such setup of K8S:

Cloudflare -> Digital Ocean Load Balancer -> Nginx Ingress -> Nginx Container

Based on my answer on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72140360/1102574) all works fine up to `Nginx Ingress` here I get the correct IP of the user.

But inside Nginx Contaier the IP is set to the service IP.

I restored it by using:

```
set_real_ip_from 0.0.0.0/0;
real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
```

But I don't trust this line: `set_real_ip_from 0.0.0.0/0;` becuase is from any IP, I can't get CIDR of ingress service.

My question is there is a better way to restore client IP inside nginx container when request are coming from Ingress Service?

Answer (score 0):

If you can read the headers forwarded by Cloudflare, a proxied request will include the `CF-Connecting-IP` header which will contain the IP of the client that connected to Cloudflare in first place.

([docs](https://developers.cloudflare.com/fundamentals/get-started/reference/http-request-headers/#cf-connecting-ip))

Answer (score 0):

There is no better way to restore the client IP.
However, you should only allow cloudflares IP address ranges with `set_real_ip_from` as described here (note that the german version of this example is much better than the english):

https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/de/articles/200170786-Wiederherstellen-von-urspr%C3%BCnglichen-Besucher-IPs-Protokollieren-von-Besucher-IP-Adressen-mit-mod-cloudflare-

```
set_real_ip_from 103.21.244.0/22;set_real_ip_from 103.22.200.0/22;set_real_ip_from 103.31.4.0/22;set_real_ip_from 104.16.0.0/12;set_real_ip_from 108.162.192.0/18;set_real_ip_from 131.0.72.0/22;set_real_ip_from 141.101.64.0/18;set_real_ip_from 162.158.0.0/15;set_real_ip_from 172.64.0.0/13;set_real_ip_from 173.245.48.0/20;set_real_ip_from 188.114.96.0/20;set_real_ip_from 190.93.240.0/20;set_real_ip_from 197.234.240.0/22;set_real_ip_from 198.41.128.0/17;set_real_ip_from 2400:cb00::/32;set_real_ip_from 2606:4700::/32;set_real_ip_from 2803:f800::/32;set_real_ip_from 2405:b500::/32;set_real_ip_from 2405:8100::/32;set_real_ip_from 2c0f:f248::/32;set_real_ip_from 2a06:98c0::/29;
```

The list of ip address ranges may change from time to time. It can be found here:
https://www.cloudflare.com/ips/